# How to get Shared preferences in doInBackground method of AsyncTask

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I am building a data transfer app using direct Wifi. I am getting the string value of extension from Uri in the onActivityResult method and storing it in Shared preferences.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

 String extension;
        Uri uri = data.getData();
 Context context =  getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        extension = "."+getMimeType(context, uri);
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = myContext.getSharedPreferences(myName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        myEdit.putString("hello", extension);
        myEdit.apply();
        
    }
```

It is working fine till now as the value of extension is storing in shared preferences successfully.  Now, in the onConnectionInfoAvailable method (related to the broadcast receiver), I am calling an AsyncTask.

```
  @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
          new FileServerAsyncTask().execute();             
}
```

Now, I  want to get the shared preference value in doInBackground method of AsyncTask. But I am not getting the value of extension from shared preferences, although my code is working fine. Please help.

```
public static class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            
            try {
                 SharedPreferences sh = myContext.getSharedPreferences(myName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String extension = sh.getString("hello", "no"); 
}....
```

Note: myContext and myName are defined as public static variables.